# Проблема со вставкой видео на устройствах с шириной экрана выше 992px

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется следующий код:

```
<div class="main-banner__video d-none d-lg-block">
</div>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
      if(window.innerWidth >= 992)
        $('.main-banner__video').html('<video src="/video/Nikola_v6_for _site_1_1.mp4" width="100%" type=\'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"\' autoplay loop muted></video>')
    };
</script>
```

Таким образом, при ширине экрана 992px и выше в контейнер должно вставляться видео, но этого не происходит. Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: а вы сразу открываете с шириной `992px` и больше?

Comment: да, сейчас пытаюсь открыть с шириной 1920px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного подправил синтаксис, и видео заработало

```
window.onload = function(){
    if($(window).width() >= 992) {
        $('.main-banner__video').html('<video src="/video/Nikola_v6_for _site_1_1.mp4" width="100%" type=\'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"\' autoplay loop muted></video>')
    }
}
```